# Scrape Dynamic Web Page in R w/o using RSelenium

Tags: r, json, web-scraping

I need to scrape the 3.5% rate for Canadian Tire High Interest Savings® Account on this page: https://www.ctfs.com/content/ctfs3/en/retailbanking/rates.html

Can this be done using a browser's *Inspect* function plus *Network* tab to see if you can determine an appropriate JSON source and then use R's JSON parsing tools to isolate the 3.5%?

Is the 3.5% stored somewhere in this list?

```
library(tibble)
library(rvest)

info <- jsonlite::read_json("https://www.ctfs.com/content/ctfs3/en.model.json")
str(info)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

One way:
It is included in [here](https://www.ctfs.com/libs/cq/i18n/dict.en.json), with the promotional material:

[image: json file above]

---

Another way:
You can get it through the retrieve demand rates page, but that requires making a request with headers.

Steps:

1. Go to your URL, open the Network tab, reload the page
2. look for a request to something called "retrieveDemandRates. Right click, and then copy as cURL (or another way, if you'd prefer, as long as you have the headers and your cookie string)
3. use this cURL request as the input to `httr2::curl_translate()`, making sure the quote marks inside of the string are escaped.
4. take the output of that function, and run it as below.

Note, the above stuff is process I went through. I have (somewhat foolishly) included my cookie, so if it doesn't work, you will only need to change the cookie.

```
pacman::p_load(httr2, tidyverse)

request("https://www.ctfs.com/bank/v2/product/retrieveDemandRates") %>% 
  req_method("POST") %>% 
  req_headers(
    Accept = "application/json",
    Referer = "https://www.ctfs.com/content/ctfs3/en/retailbanking/rates.html",
    Cookie = "tid=42c27f2f-6f26-4a2c-a72e-3bb5b1b9a210; TS01e77655=01b3ee26b0896c30d53cb628e3026d0d70c791d5444a3a1428e7beb71d9b8487069a0ccd1480cbf3e23b6d3c8ccda85cf94ce8f549; TS01994f25=01b3ee26b018aae6de329019ee69845652abe0c25d4a3a1428e7beb71d9b8487069a0ccd14f7f136ce9ca1370dbef142fbce6c58bdaad0b194d453c99b4b081d37d9f38aaf; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1693449029109r0.7343891799213128",
  ) %>% 
  req_body_raw("{\"category\":\"TFAV\",\"fund\":\"CAD\"}", "application/json") %>%
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_json()
```

Response:

```
$demandRates
$demandRates[[1]]
$demandRates[[1]]$rate
[1] 3.5

$demandRates[[1]]$minBalance
[1] 0

$demandRates[[1]]$maxBalance
[1] 0

$demandRates[[1]]$cutOffAmount
[1] 1e+13

$demandRates[[1]]$overDraftRate
[1] 0

$demandRates[[1]]$type
[1] "tfsahrs"
```

Comment: It appears the cookies change over time. How is it possible to programmatically (in R) to get the cookie data to feed into the POST request?

Comment: you'd only need to do this every few months. Just copy and paste